# EC2 Loading first vhost no matter which domain

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, vhosts

I have a new install of Ubuntu running on EC2. Everything is working perfectly other than I can't load more than one vhost at a time. Both domains are set in my hosts file as well.

I have the following running:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    #template vhost container
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.co.uk/docroot
    ServerName domain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    #template vhost container
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.co.uk/docroot
    ServerName domain1.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the security group settings set to:

```
 80 (HTTP)  0.0.0.0/0

domain.co.uk loads domain.co.uk
domain1.co.uk loads domain.co.uk
```

In my mind this should work which is why I am convinced that its something to do with EC2's security ports setting...

Comment: down vote because? You should give feedback when downvoting...

Comment: Server config issues is more for serverfault than stack overflow. Its unlikely that the security groups are causing this. Its probably somewhere in your apache config.

Comment: Yep, thanks. But I can't post there.... So I have to post here. Searching around there are loads of vhosts questions here so thought why not...

Comment: Did you ever get this working - would be interested as I've got a similar problem ...